# Sed command for replace date

Tags: shell, sed

I have a SQL query in a file which is used a `where` clause `VRFRV_DT = TO_DATE('$RUN_DT','MM-DD-YYYY'))`, I want to replace this `$RUN_DT` in my shell script with `$to_run_Dt` variable which is in (11/05/2018) format.
I have written a sed command like below, but it's not parsing. Could you please anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

```
sed 's/\$TO_RUN_DT/'$RUN_DT'/g'<<< "$q2"
```

Comment: Do you have the substitute from and to the wrong way round?

Comment: you should provide more details on what's actually happening, I think. *it's not parsing* is not a very clear description

Answer (score 1):

You can change the substitute delimiter:

```
sed 's!\$RUN_DT!'$RUN_DT'!g' <<< "$q2"
```